Drop down menu through url session create
Through paypal it is possible to create buttons with a dropdown selection.
Example : https://www.paypal.com/ncp/payment/[token]

I am having hard time implementing the same through a session url, as I'd need to also include custom Ids for the whole process, and backend logic.
When creating a normal monthly sub I use:
const response = await fetch('https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            plan_id: 'P-08L0057...', 
            custom_id: `${customId}`, 
            application_context: {
                brand_name: 'Sub',
                locale: 'en-US',
                shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
                user_action: 'SUBSCRIBE_NOW',
            },
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;

Is there a similar way, but to display a dropdown with selectable options instead?
Or do I have to make the dropdown myself and then creating an order based on that?
  const response = await fetch('https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            purchase_units: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        currency_code: 'EUR',
                        value: '6.75',
                        breakdown: {
                            item_total: { 
                                currency_code: 'EUR', 
                                value: '6.75'
                            }
                        }
                    },
...

The problem with this approach is that it stacks up all the options I'm trying to give.

For the features you're looking for, Pay links and buttons is insufficient (it's meant for simple sites without a backend) -- so yes, you have to create the order and options yourself.
I'm not sure what is meant by "it stacks up all the options I'm trying to give"; it should be possible to format the option selection UI on your site however you wish, just basic web design stuff.
